# STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes error

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, aggregate, string-aggregation

I need to combine texts by group. I found a function called `STRING_AGG`.

```
select c.id
, c.bereichsname
, STRING_AGG(j.oberbereich,',') oberBereiches 
from stellenangebote_archiv as j
join bereiche as c on j.bereich_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.bereichsname
```

But I am getting the following error:

> STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: you need to convert it see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9371/sql-string-agg-function/#:%7E:text=Error%20message%3A%20STRING_AGG%20aggregation%20result,varchar(max)%20as%20follows.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear about what you need to do. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It is likely you want a distinct list of oberbereich, but you are getting duplicates. In that case, get the distinct values in a subquery, because SQL Server's `STRING_AGG` does not accept the `DISTINCT` keyword (which I consider a design flaw).

Comment: @Charlieface lol wasn't even remotely clear in the slightest to me how to fix it! Especially since the field I was aggregating is an int.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver The error message says clearly that the result is too long. And quite clear in the documentation what the return type is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try as below

```
select c.id
, c.bereichsname
, STRING_AGG( CAST(j.oberbereich as nvarchar(MAX)),',') oberBereiches 
from stellenangebote_archiv j
join bereiche c on j.bereich_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.bereichsname
```

So the problem is the length of the concatenated string is exceeding the character limit of the result column.

So we are setting the limit to max by converting all values to "nvarchar(max)" to solve the problem.

And "STRING_AGG()" function returns what it gets.

Comment: If you add a sentence or two about why this works this will be an even better answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was busy and had to be quick. Won't happen again

Comment: @idstam if the argument is `NVARCHAR(1...4000)` then the return type is `NVARCHAR(4000)`. Same with `NVARCHAR(1...8000)` -> `NVARCHAR(8000)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` -> `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

I hope it helps: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types)

Answer (score 5):

Baris Erden Thanku soo much for the help.. it worked for me

```
SELECT Employee_Name, STRING_AGG( CAST(Project_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') as all_project_names
FROM [10.180.0.63].ware_dw.dbo.employee_360
group by Employee_Name;
```