How can I optimize a SQL query to efficiently count non-blank column values without using a cursor?
I have written a T-SQL script to count non-blank values in each column across all tables in a database. The script currently uses a cursor to iterate through each column and dynamically generate and execute SQL to count the values, excluding blanks and, in the case of date columns, excluding the date '1900-01-01'. Here is the script:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ColumnValueCounts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ColumnValueCounts;

    SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Temporary table to store the results
CREATE TABLE #ColumnValueCounts (
    TABLE_CATALOG NVARCHAR(255),
    TABLE_SCHEMA NVARCHAR(255),
    TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(255),
    COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(255),
    ORDINAL_POSITION NVARCHAR(5),
    DATA_TYPE NVARCHAR(128),
    NON_BLANK_COUNT INT
);

-- Cursor to fetch table and column names
DECLARE @TableCatalog NVARCHAR(255), @TableSchema NVARCHAR(255), @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    , @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255), @DataType NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@ORDINAL_POSITION NVARCHAR(5), @DATA_TYPE NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;

OPEN table_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableCatalog, @TableSchema, @TableName, @ColumnName, @DataType
                                    , @ORDINAL_POSITION, @DATA_TYPE;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    
    -- Dynamic SQL to count non-blank values
    SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #ColumnValueCounts 
                (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE, NON_BLANK_COUNT) 
                ' +
               'SELECT ''' + @TableCatalog + ''', ''' + @TableSchema + ''', ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @ColumnName 
               + ''', ''' + @ORDINAL_POSITION + ''', ''' + @DATA_TYPE + ''', COUNT(*) ' +
               'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
               ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' IS NOT NULL AND ' +
               CASE WHEN @DataType IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2',
                            'smalldatetime', 'datetimeoffset')
                    THEN QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' <> ''1900-01-01T00:00:00'' AND '
                    ELSE ''
               END + 
               'CONVERT(VARCHAR, ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ') <> '''' ';

    -- PRINT @Sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableCatalog, @TableSchema, @TableName, @ColumnName, @DataType
                        , @ORDINAL_POSITION, @DATA_TYPE;
END;

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;

-- Select results from the temporary table
SELECT *
FROM #ColumnValueCounts;

-- Cleanup
-- DROP TABLE #ColumnValueCounts;

The script is functional but I'm concerned about performance, especially with large databases, due to the use of a cursor. I am looking for a way to achieve the same result without using a cursor. Is there a more efficient method, perhaps using a set-based approach, to count non-blank values across multiple tables and columns?
Expected Results:
I expect to have a result set similar to what the current script produces, which is a table listing each column in the database along with a count of its non-blank values. However, the new approach should ideally reduce execution time and resource usage.
Can anyone help on this please.
Sample output



TABLE_CATALOG
TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
ORDINAL_POSITION
DATA_TYPE
NON_BLANK_COUNT




stackoverflow
dbo
WorkerDetail_1
Name
1
varchar
48


stackoverflow
dbo
WorkerDetail_1
Group
2
varchar
48


stackoverflow
dbo
WorkerDetail_1
Date
3
date
48


stackoverflow
dbo
WorkerDetail_1
Hours
4
int
48




"I'm concerned about performance, especially with large databases" Does performance matter? This should not be part of any normal process. How often do you plan to run this, and to what purpose? It suggests a failure of data integrity. Would adding check constraints help?

@DaleK, I have added the sample output.

@Schwern
Performance is crucial for periodic audits on large databases for data cleanup. We plan to run this weekly or monthly to improve data integrity. We can add a check constraint pending approval. Until then I plan to provide this to the concerned team.
I'm exploring more efficient methods than cursors.

I've seen similar, maybe identical questions before, and I think the solution is to use string_agg a couple of times instead of a cursor. Give it a crack.

I updated the cursor loop code to accumulate the select statements with UNION ALL into @Sql_insert. Then, I executed them all outside the cursor using a CTE query - completed within a minute.
Rather than executing the insert query within the loop for each column individually, this method has reduced processing time as all insertions together are done as a batch operation
SET Sql_insert  = 'WITH CTE AS (' + LEFT(@Sql_insert, LEN(@Sql_insert) - LEN('UNION ALL ') ) + ') INSERT INTO #ColumnValueCounts SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION' EXEC sp_executesql Sql_insert ;

The fastest code is the is the one that isn't run. Unless you are curious, there's no real point of doing this monthly or whatever. What will the team even do with information, it doesn't seem actionable?

Your current code will perform a table scan (or perhaps an index scan) once per column sampled. Performance can be improved by collecting all column statistics with a single scan per table.
This would require modifying your cursor loop to process one table per iteration and building dynamic SQL that not only scans the table, but has logic to test each column in that table. Those tests can be wrapped up in a CROSS APPLY that uses either a VALUES list containing appropriately conditioned CASE expressions, or a series of UNION ALL SELECTs, each having an appropriate WHERE clause. (I have elected for the latter.)
The CROSS APPLY results could consist of column identifiers for each qualifying non-blank value. Those could then be rolled up and counted with a GROUP BY and the COUNT() function, combined with column schema information, and finally inserted into your results table.
There's probably some code out there already, but I couldn't find a clean generic copy. This is my adaptation of some work I have done before:
CREATE TABLE #ColumnValueCounts (
    TABLE_CATALOG SYSNAME,
    TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME,
    TABLE_NAME SYSNAME,
    COLUMN_NAME SYSNAME,
    ORDINAL_POSITION INT,
    DATA_TYPE SYSNAME,
    NON_BLANK_COUNT INT
)

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';

DECLARE @TableSchema SYSNAME;
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME;

OPEN table_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableSchema, @TableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(S.SelectStatement AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
                          CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
                          WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT CONCAT(
                SPACE(16),
                'UNION ALL SELECT ',
                C.ORDINAL_POSITION,
                ' WHERE 1 = 1',
                CASE WHEN C.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
                     THEN ' AND T.' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NOT NULL'
                     ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2',
                                          'smalldatetime', 'datetimeoffset')
                     THEN ' AND T.' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' <> ''1900-01-01'''
                     ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
                     THEN ' AND DATALENGTH(T.' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ') > 0'
                     ELSE '' END,
                ' -- ', QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME), ' ', QUOTENAME(C.DATA_TYPE),
                CASE WHEN C.IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END
                ) AS SelectStatement
        ) S
        WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    );
    
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
        INSERT INTO #ColumnValueCounts 
            (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,
             COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE,
             NON_BLANK_COUNT)
        SELECT
            C.TABLE_CATALOG, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME,
            C.COLUMN_NAME, C.ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE,
            ISNULL(NBC.NonBlankCount, 0)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT NB.ORDINAL_POSITION, COUNT(*) AS NonBlankCount
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' T
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT 0 AS ORDINAL_POSITION WHERE 1 = 0 -- Empty result to seed the union
' + @ColumnList + '
            ) NB
            GROUP BY NB.ORDINAL_POSITION
        ) NBC
            ON NBC.ORDINAL_POSITION = C.ORDINAL_POSITION
        WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = N' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema, '''') + '
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = N' + QUOTENAME(@TableName, '''') + '
        ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION;
    ';
    
    PRINT @Sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableSchema, @TableName;
END;

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;

Note the careful use of SYSNAME, NVARCHAR types and especially QUOTENAME() to ensure safe handling of schema, table, and column names having spaces, special characters, or other UNICODE characters. The QUOTENAME(, '''') form will quote and escape string literals, but still requires the addition of the N prefix.
The innermost data is limited to the integer ORDINAL_POSITION value to avoid passing passing around expensive column name information until after the counts have been aggregated for each table. At that point, the counts are joined with the column information for the final inserts.
One of the considerations involves whether or not to treat columns containing a non-zero number of spaces as being non-blank. The above uses the DATALENGTH() function which will count columns containing spaces as non-empty. If you prefer to ignore spaces, you can change this to the LEN() function.
Other datatypes like XML, VARBINARY, of GEOMETRY might have different requirements. You can add or tailor logic to handle these as needed.
Sample generated dynamic SQL:
INSERT INTO #ColumnValueCounts 
    (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE,
     NON_BLANK_COUNT)
SELECT
    C.TABLE_CATALOG, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.COLUMN_NAME, C.ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE,
    ISNULL(NBC.NonBlankCount, 0)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT NB.ORDINAL_POSITION, COUNT(*) AS NonBlankCount
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 0 AS ORDINAL_POSITION WHERE 1 = 0 -- Empty result to seed the union
        UNION ALL SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1 AND DATALENGTH(T.[col1]) > 0 -- [col1] [varchar] NOT NULL
        UNION ALL SELECT 2 WHERE 1 = 1 AND T.[col2] IS NOT NULL AND DATALENGTH(T.[col2]) > 0 -- [col2] [varchar]
    ) NB
    GROUP BY NB.ORDINAL_POSITION
) NBC
    ON NBC.ORDINAL_POSITION = C.ORDINAL_POSITION
WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
AND C.TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION;

... (Another table)
    FROM [Some Schema].[Table Ω] T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 0 AS ORDINAL_POSITION WHERE 1 = 0 -- Empty result to seed the union
        UNION ALL SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1 AND T.[col α] <> '1900-01-01' -- [col α] [datetime] NOT NULL
        UNION ALL SELECT 2 WHERE 1 = 1 AND T.[col β] IS NOT NULL -- [col β] [int]
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 WHERE 1 = 1 -- [col γ] [int] NOT NULL
    ) NB
...

Sample results:



TABLECATALOG
TABLESCHEMA
TABLENAME
COLUMNNAME
ORDINALPOSITION
DATATYPE
NON-BLANKCOUNT




fiddle_xxx
dbo
Table1
col1
1
varchar
3


fiddle_xxx
dbo
Table1
col2
2
varchar
2


fiddle_xxx
Some Schema
Table Ω
col α
1
datetime
1


fiddle_xxx
Some Schema
Table Ω
col β
2
int
1


fiddle_xxx
Some Schema
Table Ω
col γ
3
int
2



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
One other performance consideration (and this is highly debatable) is whether or not you should use a (NOLOCK) hint. Without it, the database engine will likely place a shared (read) table-lock on each table as it is scanned. During that time, any other processes attempting to insert, update, or delete data from that table will have to wait. If this becomes an issue, you can add a (NOLOCK) hint after the FROM [schema-name].[table-name] T reference to inhibit this lock. However, if you do so, the results are not guaranteed to be accurate.  As a general rule, you should not bypass locking for ordinary production queries, but it can occasionally be justified to allow data to be sampled for debugging or administration purposes without impacting ordinary production operations.

I have made a small adjustment to add a CAST to make the result column to MAX so it doesn't fail on the STRING_AGG function
SELECT STRING_AGG(SPACE(16) + CAST(S.SelectStatement AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) , CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
This will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772996/string-agg-aggregation-result-exceeded-the-limit-of-8000-bytes-error

Good call. Updated as suggested. Also added a WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY...), just to keep the generated SQL in column ordinal order.
